# What are the state of the art models for long text similarities?

Tags: nlp

I've recently started working on news article similarity and I have tried some models but haven't been able to get vey high scores. So my task is like this:

I participated in the SemEVAL 2022 task 8, where they gave us a multilingual data set of news articles. I am only using the English news articles for now so I am not dealing with the multilingual part. The news articles have been annotated by humans in the range of 1-4 where 1 means very similar and 4 means dissimilar news. So I have two news articles and an overall similarity score from 1 to 4.

Here are some approaches I tried:

I tried a Siamese network where I built the embedding matrix by training a Word2Vec model on my data set. My Siamese network always predicted that the news articles were dissimilar by always predicting 4. This was because I was using the whole news article, so instead of doing this I trimmed the texts and only used the first 200 characters. Even though this time it wasn't predicting all 4, it was not giving very good results either.

Another approach that I used was using sentence BERT. First I sentence tokenized the news articles, encoded them using sentence BERT, then took the mean vector and calculated similarity using cosine similarity.

Another approach is tf-idf. I calculated the tf-idf vector for the news articles and calculated the cosine similarity from the resulting vectors.

I tried several more approaches but they weren't giving any better results. So far tf-idf was giving the better results among the models I've tried but this wasn't a good score.

So my question is, what are the state of the art models that I could try for this problem? or are there any steps that you suggest I could use which would give me higher results?

Note: Pearson correlation is being used for measuring the model performances.